# Cannot boot Ubuntu after successful installation on a Lenovo Laptop with no OS

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, lenovo

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my old Lenovo Laptop which currently has no operating system on it. I completely wiped the HD a while back and figured I would try to get Linux to run on it. I installed Ubuntu without issue.  When I restart after the "successful" installation, I am brought to the same screen before I installed it with the options of: Try ubuntu, Install ubuntu, and a few other things....however no option for just booting using the recently installed OS (I dont even know what it would say if it were there.
Things I have done/ tried:

Manually partitioning disk space

Changing BIOS boot order

Installing from USB

Installing from CD

Installing Linux Mint

More stuff that I cannot think of right now.

Any help would be appreciated!!

ps. I am brand new to Linux and not super technical.
Sorry if this is a dupe.

Comment: did you remove the installer after completing? so it doesn't boot back into the installer?

Comment: By remove do you mean take out the USB drive? If so, yes I did =/

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some systems require a system/recovery partition on the internal drive.

try putting a 1GB partition at the beginning of the disk. format it ntfs and flag it hidden recovery.

then use the rest of the disk to install ubuntu.

Comment: okay so during installation go to the part where I partition the drive myself, the the only thing I add is a 1GB partition like you said? Or should I add some other stuff in there as well?

Comment: just add the partition. best to do the partitioning from the live CD than the installer

Comment: I appreciate your time.... my only options are Ext4 journaling file system, ext3 j. file system, ext2 file system, btrfs journaling system, JFS journaling system, XFS journaling system, FAT16 file system, FAT32 file system, swap area, Reserved BIOS boot area, EFI system partition area, physical volume for encryption, and do not use this partition.

Comment: are you doing it with parted on the live CD or via the installer? use fat 32, if you can't get an ntfs

Comment: I was doing via the installer I kept getting an error message when I tried to continue.... I'm trying it with the CD now.